# flutter:: [ERROR] So, because 'filename' depends on both shared_preferences ^2.0.9 and flutter_audio_recorder 0.5.5, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Because every version of flutter_audio_recorder depends on file ^5.0.4 and shared_preferences_windows >=2.0.0 depends on file ^6.0.0, flutter_audio_recorder is incompatible with shared_preferences_windows >=2.0.0.
And because shared_preferences 2.0.9 depends on shared_preferences_windows ^2.0.0 and no versions of shared_preferences match >2.0.9 <3.0.0, flutter_audio_recorder is incompatible with shared_preferences ^2.0.9.
So, because mirinae_gugu depends on both shared_preferences ^2.0.9 and flutter_audio_recorder 0.5.5, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because mirinae_gugu depends on both shared_preferences ^2.0.9 and flutter_audio_recorder 0.5.5, version solving failed.)
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when you are trying to install new plugins.
try to downgrade shared_references version to non null safety version
example:

```
shared_preferences: ^0.5.6
```

or  try another versions until they are both compatible.

Comment: If the error still occurs after using this method, is there any way to fix this error?